# if let editItemVC = segue.destination as? ItemDetailViewController {} doesn't work

Tags: swift, segue

i have two segues in this tableViewController, but the downcasting in prepare(for: segue) doesn't work.

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?)
{
    print("into segue")
    super.prepare(for: segue, sender: sender)

    switch segue.identifier {
    case "addItem":
        print("addItem Segue")
        if let addItemVC = segue.destination as? ItemDetailViewController {
            print("if let done")
            addItemVC.container = container
        } else {
            print("WTF")
        }
    case "editItem":
        print("editItem Segue")
        if let editItemVC = segue.destination as? ItemDetailViewController {
            guard let selectedItemCell = sender as? PriorityListTVCell else {
                fatalError("Unexpected sender: \(String(describing: sender))")
            }
            guard let indexPath = tableView.indexPath(for: selectedItemCell) else {
                fatalError("The selected cell is not being displayed by the table")
            }

            editItemVC.editedInfo = list[indexPath.row]
            print("passed indexPath.row: \(indexPath.row)")
            editItemVC.container = container
        }
    default:
        break
    }
}
```

if i click "add" button, in the console it'll print out

```
into segue
addItem Segue
WTF
```

not sure why the downcasting doesn't work, does it have anything to do with segue types of destination?
Thanks for help!

Comment: The downcasting is not working because the destination is not a `ItemDetailViewController` instance. Make sure the `ItemDetailViewController` is not wrapped in a `UINavigationViewController`. You can also try calling `debugPrint(segue.destination)` to get more info.

Comment: Thanks a lot! i'll try take that viewController out of the navigationController and add a navigation bar myself.

Comment: no need to you can get it from the navigation see below answer

Answer (score 1):

This

```
if let addItemVC = segue.destination as? ItemDetailViewController {
```

won't work if the destination vc isn't of type ItemDetailViewController meaning you need to assign the class name in IB , for help you can do

```
print(type(of:segue.destination))
```

For navigation do

```
if let nav = segue.destination as? UINavigationController , 
   let addItemVC = nav.viewControllers?.first as? ItemDetailViewController {}
```

Comment: Thanks! and if i want to add more barButtons, i should do it in that "addItemVC" with code right?